# Getting the sum from a single column with multiple conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Scenario**

I have the following MySQL table
[image]

I am trying to sum up how many total pageCount for each visitedPage.

**Current Situation**

I am trying to do the following way, but it only helps to query sum of a single page at a time.

Eg:
`SELECT SUM(pageCount) as 'index'  FROM visitors WHERE MONTH(visitTime) = '05' AND visitedPage='index.php'`

By doing the above way, I have to run this same query for many times for all the available pages. Can someone suggest an easy way whereby I can get the sum of all the individual pages using a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT
     visitedPage
   , SUM(pageCount) as 'index'  
FROM visitors 
WHERE MONTH(visitTime) = 5 ## MONTH() returns an integer
GROUP BY
     visitedPage
```